# Execute a command within a WebView C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf

I am using WPF and have used the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView` control to host the webpage for a simple online game. The game has a button that makes the root content stretch to fullscreen (as the window).

This button is simply defined in the HTML as `<div class="fullscreen" onclick="unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"></div>`

I can open the console in a web browser and run `unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)`, but I want to do that within my webview. I've tried `MainView.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)" });`  but that just throws an exception `HRESULT: 0x80020101`

Ignore the "fullscreen" part of the question -- I just want to run that command in the webview. Is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to enable scripts and try to invoke your script this way:

```
MainView.IsScriptEnabled = true;
MainView.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);" });
```

Comment: I set `IsJavaScriptEnabled` property to `true` and this worked perfectly as expected. I'm wondering how I didn't do that. Thanks!